# Why do I get: 'ERROR: While executing gem ... (Gem::FilePermissionError)' when trying bundle install?

Tags: ruby, rubygems, rbenv

I am trying to run 'gem install bundler' on a new macbook pro.

I get :

```
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Gem::FilePermissionError)
    You don't have write permissions for the /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0 directory.
```

I have tried using RVM

I have tried using RBENV

rbenv doctor gives this output:

```
Checking for `rbenv' in PATH: /usr/local/bin/rbenv
Checking for rbenv shims in PATH: OK
Checking `rbenv install' support: /usr/local/bin/rbenv-install (ruby-build 20190423)
Counting installed Ruby versions: 1 versions
Checking RubyGems settings: OK
Auditing installed plugins: OK
```

My bash profile is like this:

```
alias brewup='brew update; brew upgrade; brew cleanup; brew doctor'

###
## Colors and prompt customisation
## OLD:  export> PS1="\[\033[36m\]\u\[\033[m\]@\[\033[32m\]\h:\[\033[33;1m\] \w\[\033[m\] \$ "
export CLICOLOR=1
export LSCOLORS=ExFxBxDxCxegedabagacad

function parse_git_branch {
git branch --no-color 2> /dev/null | sed -e '/^[^*]/d' -e 's/* \(.*\)/(\1)/'
}
export PS1="   \[\033[01;35m\]\u@\h: \[\033[01;32m\]\w \[\033[01;34m\]\$(parse_git_branch) \[\033[01;34m\]\n>\[\e[0m\]"

## NVM stuff
export NVM_DIR="$HOME/.nvm"
[ -s "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh" ] && \. "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh"  # This loads nvm
[ -s "$NVM_DIR/bash_completion" ] && \. "$NVM_DIR/bash_completion"  # This loads nvm bash_completion


## Ruby rbenv stuff
eval "$(rbenv init -)"
export PATH="/usr/local/sbin:$PATH"
export PATH="/Users/georgeclark/.gem/ruby/2.3.7/bin:$PATH"
```

the last 3 lines are vague attempts at getting this working, could well be wrong.

The output from some terminal commands I ran are as follows:

If I do `ruby -v`

I get: `ruby 2.3.7p456 (2018-03-28 revision 63024) [universal.x86_64-darwin18]`

`which gem` gives me `/Users/georgeclark/.rbenv/shims/gem`

output from:
`echo $PATH, ls -l ~/.rbenv/shims, rbenv versions, gem env`
is:
`/Users/georgeclark/.rbenv/shims:/Users/georgeclark/.gem/ruby/2.3.7/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/Users/georgeclark/.nvm/versions/node/v10.16.0/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin, ls -l /Users/georgeclark/.rbenv/shims, rbenv versions, gem env`

These seem ok.. just cant figure out why it wont run, and really don't want to use `sudo`

Comment: Are you trying to run `bundle install` or `gem install bundler`? The command `gem bundle install` makes no sense.

Comment: sorry yeah missed the r 'typo' 
`gem install bundler`


Comment: The last 2 lines in your profile are no good. `rbenv init` should be the last item in that file to ensure that the rbenv shims are first in your `PATH`.

Comment: cool thanks, put it at the end.. still the same 

Comment: Did you reload your shell and did you install a Ruby version with rbenv? What does the command `which gem` output?

Comment: Also it would be good to add the output of these commands to the end of the question: `echo $PATH`, `ls -l ~/.rbenv/shims`, `rbenv versions`, `gem env`.

Comment: Yep I installed ruby

Comment: If I do ruby -v I get:
`ruby 2.3.7p456 (2018-03-28 revision 63024) [universal.x86_64-darwin18]`

Comment: which gem:
`/Users/georgeclark/.rbenv/shims/gem`

Comment: output from:
'echo $PATH, ls -l ~/.rbenv/shims, rbenv versions, gem env'


`/Users/georgeclark/.rbenv/shims:/Users/georgeclark/.gem/ruby/2.3.7/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/Users/georgeclark/.nvm/versions/node/v10.16.0/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin, ls -l /Users/georgeclark/.rbenv/shims, rbenv versions, gem env`

Comment: Please edit the question and add the output of `gem env` to the question. Don't put it in a comment, it's too hard to read. But in any case from what I saw so far it all looks OK. It should work.

Answer (score 0):

It was my bad.

I wasn't setting the `rbenv` properly.

Once I set this up with:

`rbenv global 2.4.5`

Then all works fine.